# Como colocar o titulo da página de acordo com um produto usando JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Meu problema está na tentativa de colocar informações no título, na descrição ou trocar a imagem da página por java script.
Estou tentando fazer uma página de compras (e-commerce) com angular e na página do produto gostaria de modificar o titulo, descrição e imagem conforme o produto que está na página, até aí tudo bem, mas quando mando o link dá página no whatsapp ou facebook eles não conseguem pegar o título modificado pelo angular.
Alguém pode me ajudar??

Um exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não consegue enviar informações via scripts *client-side* (JavaScript) para sites externos que tentam puxar as informações do seu site. Isso ocorre porque sites como o Facebook, por exemplo, irá pegar as informações do HTML do seu site e não processará os scripts.

O que deve ser feito é que tais informações devem vir do seu servidor diretamente ao seu HTML.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
<title><?php echo $titulo_da_pagina; ?></title>
```

Comment: Sempre suspeitei de que eles não faziam processamento. Mas eu não queria trabalhar desse modo, estou tentando fazer uma aplicação aparte sendo alimentada por um webservice.

Comment: @JoãoEymard Blz, mas para funcionar, as informações devem estar nas tags do HTML e não em scripts.

Comment: Pois é! Descobrir na marra.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, para que o facebook e whatsapp entendam melhor as informações de sua página voce deve adicionar as metatags do OpenGraph no head da sua aplicação.

O Open Graph permite que os desenvolvedores de site transformem seus sites num objeto gráfico permitindo um certo nível de customização de uma página recomendada, curtida ou simplesmente compartilhada.

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">

<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.meusite.com.br/ola-mundo">

<meta property="og:title" content="Título da página ou artigo">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome do meu site">

<meta property="og:description" content="Minha boa descrição para intrigar os usuários.">

<meta property="og:image" content="www.meusite.com.br/imagem.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800"> /** PIXELS **/
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600"> /** PIXELS **/

/** CASO SEJA UM SITE NORMAL **/

<meta property="og:type" content="website">

/** CASO SEJA UM ARTIGO **/

<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="article:author" content="Autor do artigo">
<meta property="article:section" content="Seção do artigo">
<meta property="article:tag" content="Tags do artigo">
<meta property="article:published_time" content="date_time">
```

Mais informações você pode conseguir no http://ogp.me

Para que consiga lhe responder melhor é interessante que altere sua pergunta com mais informações... qual versão do angular esta trabalhando e nos mostrar um pouco de como está fazendo estas alterações com JS.

Comment: O schema ajuda nesse processo?

Comment: Acabei de testar aqui! Mas não deu certo! :( acredito que a página não é processada nas aplicações.

Comment: Estou usando o angular 1